# How can I add contents of a CSV file into a double[] array?

Tags: c#, csv

I am attempting to read from a CSV file and add the contents to a double[] array.

The content of the file seems to add to a string array correctly, but when trying to parse to a double array it breaks with the error:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Program Contents:

```
string[] csvFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\CSVExample.csv").Split(',');
double[] dblArray = Array.ConvertAll(csvFile, double.Parse);
foreach (double d in dblArray)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

CSV Contents:

```
10,14,7,1,19,4,15,17,16,5,13,8,18,2,12,9,3,20,6,11
6,10,13,17,4,11,5,14,19,3,9,20,15,8,1,2,18,7,12,16
13,5,11,6,4,10,9,17,19,14,1,16,12,8,7,18,20,2,15,3
2,5,4,14,20,15,3,13,7,1,12,8,19,18,11,10,9,6,16,17
```

I have also attempted:

```
double[] dblArray = dblArray.Select(s => Convert.ToDouble(s)).ToArray();
```

The same error occurred as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line breaks are part of the strings after the split, you could use this approach:

```
string[] csvFile = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\CSVExample.csv")
    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(','))
    .ToArray();
// .. rest of code same
```

Another approach is splitting by both chars:

```
string[] csvFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\CSVExample.csv")
    .Split(new[]{',', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: it should be noted that using a csv-parser is, in general, better than just splitting at commas.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann: in general yes, but not if you have created the file and know that the format is always the same. But using comma as double delimiter is not the best idea. Depending on the locale you could have doubles with comma as decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<double> dblArray = new List<double>();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                double[] dbl = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToArray();
                dblArray.AddRange(dbl);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the lines in the csv file into a string array and iterate through each line, split the elements of that line using the comma as a delimiter then parse the double element from each of the element.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\\\\Users\\\\...\\\\Documents\\\\CSVExample.csv");
//get the number of lines in the csv
var numLines = lines.ToList().Count;    
//get the number of individual numbers in a single line
var elCount = lines.ToList()[0].Split(",").Length;
//get the size of your double array
var size = numLines * elCount;
//initialize you double array
var darray = new double[size];
//initialize a variable to loop through the array with
var p = 0;
//iterate through the csv and parse double elementss and add to the array
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    var values = line.Split(',');   
    foreach(var val in values)
    {
        darray[p++] = Double.Parse(val);    
    }
}
//TO DO with the double array
//print the contents of the array to the screen
for(int i=0; i < darray.Length; i++)
{
    if(i % elCount == 0)
    {
        //break a line
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
    Console.Write(darray[i]+" ");
}
/*

10 14 7 1 19 4 15 17 16 5 13 8 18 2 12 9 3 20 6 11

6 10 13 17 4 11 5 14 19 3 9 20 15 8 1 2 18 7 12 16

13 5 11 6 4 10 9 17 19 14 1 16 12 8 7 18 20 2 15 3

2 5 4 14 20 15 3 13 7 1 12 8 19 18 11 10 9 6 16 17
*/
```